# spring-amqp with RabbitMQ does not shutdown properly

Tags: java, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

When consumer doesn't finish execution within `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` `shutdownTimeout` after `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.close()` invocation, my Spring application hangs.

Listener:

```
public class LongRunningMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("Got " + new String(message.getBody()));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished execution");
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory());
        messageListenerContainer.setQueueNames("myqueue");
        messageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(new LongRunningMessageListener());
        messageListenerContainer.setShutdownTimeout(1000);
        return messageListenerContainer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    applicationContext.close();
}
```

Output:

```
мая 08, 2015 3:43:21 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1a86f2f1: startup date [Fri May 08 15:43:21 MSK 2015]; root of context hierarchy
мая 08, 2015 3:43:22 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor start
INFO: Starting beans in phase 2147483647
мая 08, 2015 3:43:22 PM org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory createBareConnection
INFO: Created new connection: SimpleConnection@4025f2f5 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/]
Got foo1
мая 08, 2015 3:43:23 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1a86f2f1: startup date [Fri May 08 15:43:21 MSK 2015]; root of context hierarchy
мая 08, 2015 3:43:23 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor stop
INFO: Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
мая 08, 2015 3:43:23 PM org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer doShutdown
INFO: Waiting for workers to finish.
мая 08, 2015 3:43:24 PM org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer doShutdown
INFO: Workers not finished.  Forcing connections to close.
Finished execution
мая 08, 2015 3:43:27 PM org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory createBareConnection
INFO: Created new connection: SimpleConnection@260da64e [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/]
мая 08, 2015 3:43:27 PM org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory shutdownCompleted
SEVERE: Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1, class-id=60, method-id=80)
```

After that application is working infinitely.

Working threads:

```
Live threads: 14
Daemon threads: 10
```

Non daemon threads:

```
"pool-1-thread-10" #22 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fd48c93c800 nid=0x5a07 waiting on condition [0x0000000129eb3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000796333168> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"pool-1-thread-9" #21 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fd48b9d8000 nid=0x540b waiting on condition [0x0000000129db0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000079633dfb0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672" #20 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fd48d186000 nid=0x530b runnable [0x0000000129cad000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    - locked <0x000000079632e8f0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
    - locked <0x000000079632e8d0> (a java.io.DataInputStream)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"DestroyJavaVM" #19 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fd48d002000 nid=0x1303 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Everything is fine if I increase `shutdownTimeout`, but timeout behavior looks like a bug.

Spring versions:

```
spring-amqp 1.4.5.RELEASE
spring-rabbit 1.4.5.RELEASE
spring-context 4.1.5.RELEASE
```

**Update**:
I've replaced calls of System.out.println by `Log` invocations and configured log4j for logging. Pattern: `%r [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n`

Output:

```
0 [main] DEBUG StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
3 [main] DEBUG StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
4 [main] DEBUG StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
130 [main] INFO  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@73a8dfcc: startup date [Fri May 08 17:07:06 MSK 2015]; root of context hierarchy
132 [main] DEBUG AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Bean factory for org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@73a8dfcc: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1593948d: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,config]; root of factory hierarchy
178 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
179 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
232 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
235 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
288 [main] DEBUG ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method Config.messageListenerContainer()
288 [main] DEBUG ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method Config.connectionFactory()
431 [main] DEBUG ConfigurationClassEnhancer - Successfully enhanced Config; enhanced class name is: Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b6627e0a
432 [main] DEBUG ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Replacing bean definition 'config' existing class name 'Config' with enhanced class name 'Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b6627e0a'
436 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
436 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
438 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
438 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
438 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
438 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
439 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
439 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
439 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
439 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
445 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
445 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
445 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
445 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
445 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
446 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
446 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
446 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
446 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
446 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
450 [main] DEBUG AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@27d415d9]
454 [main] DEBUG AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@b3d7190]
461 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1593948d: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,config,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,messageListenerContainer,connectionFactory]; root of factory hierarchy
461 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
462 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
462 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
462 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
462 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'config'
463 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'config'
468 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'config' to allow for resolving potential circular references
494 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'config'
494 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
494 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
494 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'messageListenerContainer'
495 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'messageListenerContainer'
497 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'config'
551 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'connectionFactory'
551 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'connectionFactory'
552 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'config'
595 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'connectionFactory' to allow for resolving potential circular references
609 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'connectionFactory'
609 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'connectionFactory'
638 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'messageListenerContainer' to allow for resolving potential circular references
707 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'messageListenerContainer'
708 [main] DEBUG SimpleMessageListenerContainer - No global properties bean
708 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'messageListenerContainer'
708 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'connectionFactory'
710 [main] DEBUG AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@b62fe6d]
710 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'messageListenerContainer'
710 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
716 [main] INFO  DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 2147483647
716 [main] DEBUG DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting bean 'messageListenerContainer' of type [class org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer]
716 [main] DEBUG SimpleMessageListenerContainer - No global properties bean
716 [main] DEBUG SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Starting Rabbit listener container.
767 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG BlockingQueueConsumer - Starting consumer Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
852 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO  CachingConnectionFactory - Created new connection: SimpleConnection@25c0a36 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/]
869 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG CachingConnectionFactory - Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1)
911 [pool-1-thread-3] DEBUG BlockingQueueConsumer - ConsumeOK : Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
914 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG BlockingQueueConsumer - Storing delivery for Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
915 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG BlockingQueueConsumer - Started on queue 'myqueue' with tag amq.ctag-KkQJOq3Z0r8Uc0JwcKdGxQ: Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-KkQJOq3Z0r8Uc0JwcKdGxQ=myqueue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=1
916 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-KkQJOq3Z0r8Uc0JwcKdGxQ=myqueue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=1
920 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG BlockingQueueConsumer - Received message: (Body:'foo5'MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=0, redelivered=true, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=myqueue, deliveryTag=1, messageCount=0])
921 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO  LongRunningMessageListener - Got foo5
921 [main] DEBUG DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Successfully started bean 'messageListenerContainer'
931 [main] DEBUG PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
932 [main] DEBUG PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
933 [main] DEBUG PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
1938 [main] INFO  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@73a8dfcc: startup date [Fri May 08 17:07:06 MSK 2015]; root of context hierarchy
1938 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'messageListenerContainer'
1938 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
1939 [main] INFO  DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
1939 [main] DEBUG DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Asking bean 'messageListenerContainer' of type [class org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer] to stop
1939 [main] DEBUG SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Shutting down Rabbit listener container
1941 [main] INFO  SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Waiting for workers to finish.
1941 [pool-1-thread-5] DEBUG BlockingQueueConsumer - Received cancellation notice for tag amq.ctag-KkQJOq3Z0r8Uc0JwcKdGxQ; Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2946 [main] INFO  SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Workers not finished.  Forcing connections to close.
2946 [main] DEBUG DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Bean 'messageListenerContainer' completed its stop procedure
2946 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1593948d: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,config,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,messageListenerContainer,connectionFactory]; root of factory hierarchy
2946 [main] DEBUG DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'messageListenerContainer'
2946 [main] DEBUG SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Shutting down Rabbit listener container
2946 [main] DEBUG DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'connectionFactory'
5923 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO  LongRunningMessageListener - Finished execution
5927 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO  CachingConnectionFactory - Created new connection: SimpleConnection@5d0224dc [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/]
5928 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
5929 [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] ERROR CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1, class-id=60, method-id=80)
6932 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Cancelling Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
6933 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG BlockingQueueConsumer - Closing Rabbit Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1)
6933 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG CachingConnectionFactory - Closing cached Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1)
```

Comment: Please repost logs including the thread name (e.g. `%t` in log4j)

Comment: @GaryRussell, I've added log4j output.

Comment: Thanks; so you are simply saying that if a listener takes longer than the `shutdownTimeout`, the container doesn't stop properly?

Comment: Yes, application is not stopped at all in that case.

Comment: What is your RabbitMQ version ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan, RabbitMQ 3.5.1. But I think it's doesn't matter. Seems problem occurs when `CachedConnectionFactory#destroy` is called before the stop of the listener

Comment: I confirm that we have an issue with timeouts dance. Please, raise a JIRA ticket on the matter: https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP. Looks like threads must be interrupted on the "force" `connectionFactory.close()`

Comment: Please, add managed `Executor` to your container: `messageListenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(executor());`

Comment: `@Bean
public Executor executor() {
 return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
}`

Comment: Spring `destroy` it on ctx `close()`, hence you hanging `Thread` will be interrupted. I mean that long-living listener thread.

Comment: I've tried this solution as well. It works for this simple case (Thread.sleep()), but does not work when listener is doing "real" job with long-waiting IO for example.

Comment: I've submitted issue by the way
https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-496

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comment on the question (in response to @Artem's work-around)...

> I've tried this solution as well. It works for this simple case (Thread.sleep()), but does not work when listener is doing "real" job with long-waiting IO for example.

There's nothing the framework can do if user code is in an uninterruptible state such as waiting on a socket I/O. You need to close the socket somehow.

Comment: It's OK if application will not dead while workers in uninterruptible state, but after some time they will become interruptible (just after message processing). However, application will not finish execution it that case too because of framework's internal non daemon running threads.

By the way System.exit() is suitable workaround.

Comment: Right the fix for the JIRA will correct that; I am just saying we can't do anything about uninterruptible code.